# Best practice for importing Typescript namespaces in VS2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am writing an AngularJS app using Typescript within VS2015.  The current codebase imports objects like so

```
import IUser = App.Interface.IUser;

class TestClass
{
    users: IUser[];
}
```

The problem with this, in VS2015 at least, is that it breaks intellisense and "Go to declaration" as `IUser`, in its mind, is declared at the top of the module and takes you there instead of the actual definition.

Another way to do this, I found, is to do this:

```
import Interface = Verilocation.App.Interface;

class TestClass
{ 
    users: Interface.IUser[];
}
```

But doing this inside my module definition seems to break the colouration on `Interface.IUser` but "Goto definition" works.  Having the declaration outside my namespace doesnt break anything but then pollutes the global namespace with my import variable.

Is there another / better way of importing types across files or am I stuck with what I have?  Im currently tempted to just be literal on every type (i.e. use full namespace)

```
users: Verilocation.App.Interface.IUser[];
```